# 1px black line in Firefox full screen mode

Tags: css, firefox, fullscreen

In Firefox, there is a 1PX black line on top of the screen in full-screen mode.

Is there any way to remove it with website CSS code?

Comment: would be nice to see what your are talking about

Comment: Mr. Banana, "There is a 1PX black line on top of the screen in full-screen mode". Which part is ambiguous?

Comment: Mr Agamemnus, the part where i dont have any black line in my fullscreen mode in firefox. if you encounter any issue, please be more specific. if you are going to ask questions like "i have a black line, how do i remove it"  you will get an answer like "take scissors and cut it out"

Comment: What version are you using? Seems to be an issue since 2008...

Comment: well, im not a firefox fan, i just downloaded version 28.0 to see what you meant and i didnt have any black line on any website i tried neither in normal mode nor fullscreen... can you attach a printscreen please?

Comment: I just installed 29. If go to full screen mode, you do a print screen and zoom in, you will see there is a 1px black line on top: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=702635 This can no doubt be fixed in some way by modifying personal Firefox settings, but again I am looking for a website CSS method.

Comment: @Agamemnus The black line is not part of the window content, so there won't be a CSS-only solution. Have you tried the solutions in the mozillaZine thread?

Comment: Hmm, unfortunate. I am designing a web-app to a full-screen ratio and size (eg: 1920x1080), and when it is off by one pixel everything goes a bit wonky. (I haven't tried the solutions in the forum topic yet.)

Comment: OK... how do you determine what the maximum size of the viewport is? If you're using `screen.height` you'd be better off using `window.innerHeight`.

Comment: I am using window.innerHeight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following snippet to [your userChrome.css file](http://lifehacker.com/197715/customize-firefox-with-userchromecss) to make the 1px black line completely transparent (and thereby invisible) while preserving the default functionality of displaying the tab bar when you mouse-over the top 1px of the screen:

```
#fullscr-toggler { background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important; }
```

Alternatively, if you don't want the tab bar to be revealed when you mouse-over the top 1px of the screen, then use this snippet instead of the one shown above:

```
#fullscr-toggler { display: none; }
```

See [this old (locked) MozillaZine forum thread](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=702635) for more information.

Comment: Great. I had given up on it. OK, now I just need to make the "Firefox 2 theme for Firefox 4+ v. 2.0.1" compatible for FF 34. ^_^

Comment: I use the [Classic Theme Restorer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/classicthemerestorer/) extension (you'll have to tweak its configuration quite a bit) to achieve that classic Firefox 2 appearance.